# Fitting a plane to many points in 3D

Tags: regression, lm, least-squares, plane

I have a set of ~700 points and am trying to find a plane with minimal distances to all points.

```
head(data)
          V6     V7     V8
10664  16.80  10.00 107.28
10714  24.15   5.07 108.32
10764  26.37  27.91  68.55
10814  64.15 110.30 108.90
10864 110.31 103.40 107.79
10914 105.08  99.12  69.36
```

```
plot <- scatterplot3d(data, type="p", highlight.3d=TRUE, angle=55, 
scale.y=0.7, pch=16, main="Fitting a plane to N points")

reg <- lm(data)
```

summary(reg)  returns this output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = data)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-80.572 -38.094  -0.155  39.212  77.469 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 78.82248    8.20208   9.610   <2e-16 ***
V7          -0.01363    0.03754  -0.363    0.717    
V8          -0.01541    0.08503  -0.181    0.856    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 44.51 on 689 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.0002333, Adjusted R-squared:  -0.002669 
F-statistic: 0.08037 on 2 and 689 DF,  p-value: 0.9228
```

and if I add the plane to the scatterplot it does not seem to be fitted correctly which doesn't look correct:

```
plot$plane3d(78.82248, -0.01363, -0.01541, lty.box = "solid")
```

[See the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkwWW.png)

Comment: Would you please post a link to the full data set?

Comment: Please find the data here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Fm_mmyrATf3qtEk7DUu6EigGPMbku9-9

Answer (score 0):

I have independently verified that - per your scatter plot - this data set is two parallel flat point clouds, see image below. When I fit to the flat surface equation "V8 = a + (b * V6) + (c * V7)" I get the parameters a = 8.8327170551088543E+01, b = -3.0935322191121724E-03, and c = -1.4075477287696175E-02

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks. Specifying the formula solved the problem.

```
reg <- lm(formula = data$V8 ~ data$V6 + data$V7)
```
Btw, may I ask what package do you use to plot the surface? Thanks

Comment: Since you ask, I used my online zunzun.com open source curve and surface fitting web site. Specifically, I pasted the data into the URL for this surface equation at http://zunzun.com/Equation/3/Polynomial/Linear/ and then hit the Submit button.